# $timeout not working correctly with ng-class

Tags: angularjs, timeout, ng-class

I was trying to do something like

```
$timeout(function() {
  if (someCondition === true) {
    _this.isVariantShowSaving = true;
  }
}, 50);
```

in a controller (note:I used controllerAs syntax saved `var _this = this;`) that related to a dom that has follow properties

```
class="pricing-info"  ng-class="{ 'pricing-info variant-hide-savings' : !expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving }"
```

for some reason the `class="pricing-info"` has been completely wiped, when `isVariantShowSaving` toggled form false to true by the timeout....

I can't imagine what is the issue. Thought?

Comment: you are clearly telling it to be removed in `ng-class`. What is expected behavior?

Comment: @charlietfl I do not quit understand what you said. the intend of ng-class is to override the default of `pricing-info` with `pricing-info variant-hide-savings` when condition of `!expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving` met. But what I got is erased default of `pricing-info` but it failes to apply 'pricing-info variant-hide-savings'

Comment: it works well if I just set the `expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving` to true / false follow the flow within the controller script, but once I start use it in `$timeout` or in another format,` ng-click` to toggle `expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving` will also cause the disappearance of default class without the new classes.

Comment: well that is your interpretation of what you ***want*** it to do It will use `toggleClass()` internally and that does what you are seeing. Read the jQuery API docs since that's what `angular.element` is a subset of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is NOT with `$timeout` for in any case there is in need for two different expressions, one should always do

```
<div ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

in my case `expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving` and `! expressDealCtrl.isVariantShowSaving` are TWO expressions.

*Spent at least 4 hours on this... hope it helps someone :)

Cheers!